# My ipad project does not run on a real ipad device

Tags: xcode, ipad, project-settings

I cannot figure out why it's not working. I run the project on the simulator. It works fine, I test it on the ipad, it does not run. When launch, a black screen appears and it does not even enter the delegate.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved :p it was the path to the files which were wrong and therefore the project could not find them on the device.